# Java client side source files for CKFinder

Tags: ckeditor4.x, ckfinder, ckfinder3

I would like to upgrade client-side part of CKFinder to the latest version for a java application

CKFinder downloads -  https://ckeditor.com/ckfinder/download/ does not contain UI related files for Java

**How can I get the client-side code of CKFinder? Is it bundled along with CKEditor?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java static files can be downloaded from CKFinder JAR archive:

1. wget https://maven.cksource.com/com/cksource/ckfinder3/3.5.1/ckfinder3-3.5.1.jar
2. unzip ckfinder3-3.5.1.jar
3. CKFinder's client side part can be found in static/ckfinder directory.

Refer below link for more details:
https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder/issues/452

Also, client-side part for ASP and PHP is available along with its zip file - https://ckeditor.com/ckfinder/changelog/